# Who were the toadstool people chasing Cinnamon Bun?

Tags: adventure-time

Who were the toadstool people chasing Cinnamon Bun in the *Adventure Time* episode "Lady Rainicorn of the Crystal Dimension"?

Comment: Well this cartoon sounds perfectly mundane and not at all like it was written by a team of writers who've just discovered shrooms :-)

Comment: @Valorum - What's so odd about a cartoon featuring a human, his talking dog with Plastic Man's powers, and an entire race of people who are candies and pastries?

Comment: If it were not a bit odd, it would not be in scope. )